# Commands out of sync, even though first SQL query does not contain results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been reading about the `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` problem for some time now, and see that you cannot have any unread results left, which makes sense to me. However, in the following case, I don't see which results I am missing to free. I have left out the irrelevant things from my PHP and SQL code below.

```
# Set local variables
$sql = "
    SET @STARTDATE = '2014-09-01';
    SET @RANK = 0;
";
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
    # Success: do nothing else
} else {
    # Failure: output the error message
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

# Fetch and store the results
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM MyTable
";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

The second query (the `if (!$result)` block) returns the infamous `Commands out of sync` error. If I comment out the first part, the second query runs no problem. If I change the first query into only one `SET` statement instead of two, the second query runs no problem. Therefore, it seems that I have to clear the 'success-flag' of every individual SQL statement from the first part. Is this correct? If so, how shall this be done?

**EDIT**: indeed it seems you have to flush all results in between. Adding the following line between part 1 and part 2 solves the problem.

```
while (mysqli_next_result($conn)) {;} // Flush multi_queries
```

I found this solution in a user comment on the PHP manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, your first query

```
SET @STARTDATE = '2014-09-01';
SET @RANK = 0;
```

Will generate 2 result sets and until they have been processed, even though the result will be just a status you cannot continue.

So you need to do something like this :-

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
    do {
        /* unload result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            // Check status
            $result->free();
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
} else {
    # Failure: output the error message
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Of course you should probably check for errors in that loop